# DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN error on Heroku

Tags: heroku, dns, hosting, nameservers

I have deployed an app on Heroku, and everything is going great when the app is being accessed from the herokuapp.com domain. I tried adding a custom domain and have followed the instructions from the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains), but unfortunately, I encounter a DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN error when trying to access the app from my custom domain.

Some [articles](https://help.heroku.com/NH44MODG/my-root-domain-isn-t-working-what-s-wrong) pointed out how Heroku requires the usage of ALIAS ANAME or FLATTENING records, which may not be available in DNS providers. I am using a local DNS provider where Name Server configuration is not directly accessible, and only the DNS provider admin can configure it on my request, so I am unable to check the CNAME Records and such (probably because I use .id domain, which I believe to have a somewhat specific configuration due to its affiliation with the country Indonesia, could be wrong though).

For my Name Server, because my DNS Provider requires at least two different name servers, I registered the domains for my Heroku app (from the Heroku settings dashboard > add domain and from the CLI) as follows:

1. my-domain.id
2. *.my-domain.id
3. [www.my-domain.id](http://www.my-domain.id)

Is there anything I can do to fix this? Any help would be highly appreciated! Thank you!

EDIT:
I have just been informed by my DNS provider admin that the name servers I used, which I got from Heroku ([haiku].herokudns.com) does not have IP address. Is there anything I did wrong on the configuration?

Comment: What DNS servers did Heroku ask you to configure?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out I managed to find my own mistake! It turns out that I provided the DNS Target as Name Server to my provider, which is totally not the same thing. What solved my problem was simply asking the provider to register a CNAME with the DNS target from Heroku as the value.

Be sure to provide the correct DNS Target for the domains as the DNS Target produced for registering root domains like your-domain.com will be different from the DNS Target produced for registering subdomains like [www.your-domain.com](http://www.your-domain.com) or when using wildcard tag (*.your-domain.com). Also, note that Heroku [doesn't recommend](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/apex-domains#limitations) the usage of A Record for root domains, so be sure that your DNS Provider supports the record types needed as [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#configuring-dns-for-root-domains) Heroku article suggests.

Thank you @Ruurtjan Pul for getting in touch! Hope this helps!